# PDF form that allows placing of image in Reader

Tags: pdf

I'm asked to create a document that users can customise with their own logo. How can this be done without the end-user using paid-for software?

I've found out that a form button could be created that runs a Javascript (event.target.buttonImportIcon();), but in Reader this only allows you to place a PDF.

Secondly, I've heard that it can be done with Adobe LifeCycle Designer, but I don't have that software (got Adobe CC only).

Is there any other way, e.g. doing it through a website where a user would upload an image and then a final PDF is generated?

May thanks!

Comment: I have a ton of questions. What kind of document? A letter, with fixed text, a simple one page logo, a photo with a logo as watermark? Is that photo or text changing besides the logo? Is it to be uploaded  online? Do you use a server side script? Can't you simply cut and paste a Libre Office document? The logo should automaticly resize?

Comment: You can either provide a graphic-to-image conversion service, or use a server-side filling tool, like FDFMerge by Appligent, which does properly merge graphics into the according field in the base form. If you have more programming resources than investment budget, there are also a bunch of libraries which provide the functionality to place a graphic on the document.

Comment: I think website-to-PDF would be the best solution as it requieres nothing else than a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have already solved your problem.

You are correct that you must use this JavaScript:

> event.target.buttonImportIcon();

However, in the dialog that appears for uploading your file, you should be able to change the file type that is accepted in the bottom right of the upload window. You can change this to JPG, PNG, or whatever.

I believe this should solve your problem!

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for users with Acrobat, but for users that have Acrobat Reader only, they can only place PDF files – annoyingly.

Comment: After further research, it seems you're correct. I've tried downloading all the latest versions of Reader and had no luck so far. Sorry mate.

Comment: This works with Reader XI and newer. However, Reader requires to icon to be a PDF; you might therefore have to provide graphic-to-PDF converter (or service).